# Contact form not working(Materialize+PHP)

Tags: php, html, material-design, contact-form, materialize

I have been trying to send messages from my contact form with materializecss and PHP.But for some strange reasons, I couldn't accomplish it.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

$to = 'soundharyabharatiya@gmail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@soundharya.info\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

My materialize contact form

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   <h4>Contact</h4>
    <form action="contact_me.php" method="POST" class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate" name="name">
          <label for="icon_prefix">Full Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
          <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
          <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" name="email">Email</label>
        </div>        
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">message</i>
          <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" name="message"></textarea>
          <label for="textarea1">Message</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container center">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </div>
  </div>
```

I cannot even send a single piece of the message to my email id.

Comment: please specify the error message displayed. Sometimes the server does not support the php mail function so do check for that.
Your submit button should be inside closing form tag.

Comment: In order to submit the form the button "Submit" should be inside "form" tag.

Comment: Yeah @Niraj. I didn't notice. Thanks for your help.